# Should icons ever change on their own based on background colors selected?

Tags: user-interface, icons

A requirment has been given that the desktop icon change colors "to fit well" with the users chosen desktop color.  Not only is that a vague requirement but it is not the standard way that applications behave.  The correct solution is to provide a number of icons which the users can select from.  I just think its a bad idea.  We are in the requirments phase still and I feel like I am becoming antagonistic.  Standard practices exist for a reason but I am about to lose my cool because fully 15% of the 300 requirements fall into this category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. defer the argument by putting this on a "nice to have" list (that will never get implemented because it adds nothing to the functionality and creates disproportionate configuration problems) and concentrating on the real features that actually do important things
2. suggest a transparent icon so that it blends exactly with the desktop colors (see if they realize that it would be invisible!)
3. give a very long list of why this feature is ridiculous, create enemies, make the customer/manager feel stupid...not really recommended

bear in mind that you may be dealing with people that *mean well* but *don't know much* technically. Say "that's an interesting idea" to validate their feeling/input/existence, and go on to more important things. ;-)

Comment: Next someone says interesting idea I am going to remember you... keep that in mind.

Comment: @[ojblass]: that's an interesting idea, it's nice to be remembered! ;-)